# Горизонтальный скролл колесом мышки и ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть контейнер с горизонтальным скролом overflow-x: auto;

Задача - сделать так, чтобы при наведенной мышке на этот контейнер, скрол прокручивался с помощью колеса мышки и при этом вертикальный скролл страницы не работал.

В сети нашел такой код  и он рабочий, однако в функционале есть добавление в этот контейнер элементов с помощью ajax, после чего все перестает работать.

```
  $('.compare-table__scroll').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function doVerticalScroll(event) {
const delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail)));
$(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft() - (delta * 40));
event.preventDefault();});
```

Пробовал вешать на document

```
  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', '.compare-table__scroll', function doVerticalScroll(event) {

const delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail)));
$(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft() - (delta * 40));
event.preventDefault();});
```

но в таком случае выдает в консоли такую ошибку и скролл на элементе работает и вертикально и горизонтально.
**[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.**